# run Sandcastle in cmd

Tags: build, sandcastle

as part of our build process i would like to write a batch file that run the Sandcastle in one of our dll, i know how to do it by the gui, and i'm wondering if there is nay way todo it by commad line

thanks
Tova

Answer (score 3):

You might consider invoking sandcastle help file builder via MsBuild as a post build event, as discussed in this question: [Build Sandcastle Documentation When Building Visual Studio Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882746/build-sandcastle-documentation-when-building-visual-studio-project).  Sandcastle help file builder project files (.shfb) are actually valid msbuild files.  You can generate shfb files with the Visual Studio integration or Sandcastle Help File Builder GUI as msorens mentions, and you can make a call like: `msbuild My_SHFB_Project.shfbproj` at the command line.  You can find more at http://shfb.codeplex.com/