# How should I generate documentation for my web service API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, documentation

I am exposing my API through web service (`.asmx`). Currently, the only thing available is the  default WSDL help page. While this is immensely helpful, it is not sufficient if my target audience requires a little more hand-holding. For instance, let us say I want to include some examples but still need automatic generation of method signatures etc.

Is there a good semi-automated (automatic method signatures but still be able to provide examples) to achieve this? I am looking for something like [this](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) which is also maintainable. Ideally something that helps me modify the default WSDL (I really like that page) would be great. *All I need is for the documentation to be automatically available along with the service when it is deployed.*

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe easiest way is to use XML documentation comments.

[XML Documentation Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx)

Using these comment you can automatically generate HTML documentation. For example using [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) or [NDoc3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndoc3/):

[Build Sandcastle Documentation When Building Visual Studio Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882746/build-sandcastle-documentation-when-building-visual-studio-project)

And after all you can automatically save html documentation into shared location near your service, and it could be easily navigated there using browser. So, all could be near - wsdl + html documentation

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy. If you decorate all your classes and methods with tripple /// comments then you could generate documentation from it. See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233217.aspx

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84436/documentation-made-easy-with-c-and-xml/

Answer (score 0):

Agree with other posters, however I've used NDoc3 with a lot of success. It's quite a bit faster than Sandcastle (which is a very good tool as well). NDoc3 will create .chm, .doc, and .html output.

NDoc3 and Sandcastle both generate MSDN-style documentation.

NDoc3 - http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndoc3/